# Getting "Unable to evaluate the expression." while debugging my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to debug my controller but I'm getting the error message "Unable to evaluate the expression" in my Watch window and my Locals and Autos window do not display anything at all.
[image: The watch window showing the error]

What is the problem here? How can get I see my variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Async CTP installed? You can't have both Async CTP and ASP.Net MVC 3 RC installed at the same time(debug will not work in VS). Look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/11/a-few-quick-asp-net-mvc-3-installation-notes.aspx